# Is it fine to keep Firestore Document Snapshots inside cloud functions?

Tags: function, google-cloud-firestore, cloud

For ex. I have 1000 documents that I need to sort using a mathematical formula.

What I did was create a real time snapshot on my cloud function serving in the background that populates a global array

```
const places = [];

admin.firestore().collection("places").where("latitude", ">", 0)
    .onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.docChanges.forEach(function(change) {
            if (change.type === "added") {
                shops.push(change.doc.data());
        }
```

Now I have a function that can retrieve the places variable like this

```
exports.getPlacesList = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return places;
```

Is it ok to retrieve data like this so that if I have 1000 or more users they will not need to retrieve directly from firestore and avoid too much database reads?

Comment: I meant "places.push(change.doc.data());" inside forEach